# How can I add an id from flask's global 'g' object in the access log?

Tags: python, logging, flask, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn to run my Flask app.

I have an `user_id` on Flask's global `g` object that I want to log on each authenticated request.

Does anyone know a good way to do that? I tried adding a custom filter like this, but the request doesn't seem to be in scope at the time the logger is executed:

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        if hasattr(g, 'user_id'):
            record.msg = "User ID: {0} ".format(g.user_id) + record.msg
        return 1
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
2014-11-08 21:52:15 [INFO] REQUESTLOG 127.0.0.1 User ID: 12345 "GET /v1.0/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 51 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass the Werkzeug request handler and provide your own version of the `log_request()` method. Here is an example:

```
from werkzeug.serving import BaseRequestHandler
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hi"

class MyRequestHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
        self.log('info', 'custom log! "%s" %s %s', self.requestline, code, size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, request_handler=MyRequestHandler)
```

Comment: Cool thanks @Miguel. How do I specify the request handler if I'm running through `gunicorn` though?

Comment: @greegles: I'm confused. If you are running gunicorn then you are not running Werkzeug, so this code never runs. The log that you are getting must be from gunicorn then, not Werkzeug.

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. The log is coming from gunicorn, but I'm still looking for a way to add custom attributes from the flask `g` object. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know. Putting a Flask-specific thing in the gunicorn log sounds much more difficult, gunicorn knows nothing about Flask or its application/request contexts. I recommend that you write your own log with this information.